# How to compare value in Pandas DataFrame against a value in the previous row AND the previous column?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of two columns filled with float values. I need to calculate all the values of 'h' minus all the values of 'c', at the index previous to the current 'h' value.
So for instance, for 'h' in row 1, I need to calculate 1.17322 - 1.17285 (the value of 'c' in the previous row)
I have tried several different methods to accomplish this, including the use of: .iloc, .shift(), .groupby(), and .diff(), but I cannot get exactly what I'm looking for.

If anybody could help, it would be greatly appreciated

```
    c        h
0   1.17285  1.17310
1   1.17287  1.17322
2   1.17298  1.17340
3   1.17346  1.17348
4   1.17478  1.17511
5   1.17595  1.17700
6   1.17508  1.17633
7   1.17474  1.17545
8   1.17463  1.17546
9   1.17224  1.17468
10  1.17437  1.17456
11  1.17552  1.17641
12  1.17750  1.17784
13  1.17694  1.17770
```

Comment: Try `df.h.shift(-1)-df.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), for as an example:

```
df['c_shift'] = df['c'].shift()
df['diff'] = df['h'] - df['c_shift']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          c        h  c_shift     diff
0   1.17285  1.17310      NaN      NaN
1   1.17287  1.17322  1.17285  0.00037
2   1.17298  1.17340  1.17287  0.00053
3   1.17346  1.17348  1.17298  0.00050
4   1.17478  1.17511  1.17346  0.00165
5   1.17595  1.17700  1.17478  0.00222
6   1.17508  1.17633  1.17595  0.00038
7   1.17474  1.17545  1.17508  0.00037
8   1.17463  1.17546  1.17474  0.00072
9   1.17224  1.17468  1.17463  0.00005
10  1.17437  1.17456  1.17224  0.00232
11  1.17552  1.17641  1.17437  0.00204
12  1.17750  1.17784  1.17552  0.00232
13  1.17694  1.17770  1.17750  0.00020
```

Of course, you can do this in one step:

```
df['diff'] = df['h'] - df['c'].shift()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was what I needed.